# C# Regex for only numbers from string

Tags: c#, regex

I have string with letters and numbers and I want have only numbers.
For example:

```
string str = "4.2 43 f-2.1-1k 4. a.1 5asd11 54 -1.99";
Regex regex = new Regex("?????");            
Match m;
m = regex.Match(str);

while (m.Success)
{
    try
    {
        buffor[index] = float.Parse(m.ToString());
        index++;                      
    }
    catch (FormatException ex) { }
    m = m.NextMatch();             
}
```

In buffer array I want to have `4.2 43 4 54 -1.99`. When `regex = [ ][+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+[ ]` I have in buffer only `43` and `54`.

Comment: Why is `4.2` not a number?  It was a number, last time I checked.

Comment: Why to you have just a space at the beginning and end?  You need [^ ] and [ $]

Comment: Does it have to be `Regex`? Why not loop through the `char`s in the `string` and ignore all non-numeric character?

Comment: Can you tell me what it should look like?

Comment: Why is - 2.1 not part of the output?

Comment: @afaolek because you would loose + - and the decimal separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [modified](http://rextester.com/LNCQA97432) slightly your snippet using the next regex `(?<=^| )([-+]?\d+\.?(?:\d+)?)(?= |$)`.

```
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "4.2 43 f-2.1-1k 4. a.1 5asd11 54 -1.99";
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=^| )([-+]?\d+\.?(?:\d+)?)(?= |$)");            
            Match m;
            m = regex.Match(str);

            while (m.Success)
            {
                 try
                {
                    //buffor[index] = float.Parse(m.ToString());
                    //index++;
                    Console.WriteLine(float.Parse(m.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                }
                catch (FormatException ex) { }
                m = m.NextMatch();             
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i have the question about how will you process numbers in the exponential notation.

Comment: Ok, thank You very much. Do you know how it could be improved and add new line and tab characters to make it work? If `str="4.2 43 f-2.1-1k 4. a.1 5asd11 54 -1.99\r\n5\r\n4.4\t123"` and we have in array extra 5 4.4 and 123?

Answer (score 0):

I used below code for that:

```
var str = "4.2 43 f-2.1-1k 4. a.1 5asd11 54 -1.99";
var result =
    Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<=^|\s)(?<num>[\-+]?[0-9\.]*[0-9]+)([\s\.]|$)")
        .OfType<Match>()
        .Select(c => float.Parse(c.Groups["num"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Explanation:

```
(?<=                 //-> check before match if
    ^|\s             //-> it's start of string -'^'- or a space character -'\s'-
)                    
(?<num>              // match with grouping and naming by 'num'
    -?               // an optional -'?'- dash
    [0-9\.]*         // optional dot or digits
    [0-9]+           // some digits
)
(                    //-> then check for
    [\s\.]|$         //-> dot -'\.'- or a space character or end of string -'$'-
)
```